# Print nested list with 10 numbers in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone tell me how to print a nested list containing numbers 1-100, and the row should be 10 numbers.

Like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
new row
...
```

...and so on.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a list comprehension that calls `range` for the outside list and again for the inside list:

```
[list(range(i, i+10)) for i in range(1,100,10)]

>>> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
    [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
    [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
    [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50],
    [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60],
    [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70],
    [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80],
    [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90],
    [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]]
```